# Music Button missing from Cortana

Tags: 8.1, cortana

I'm missing the music button from Cortana page. When I try to do "what song is playing", it always tells me that there is a problem with internet connection. My device is HTC 8s if it's relevant.

Comment: Have You tried restarting your Phone and making a factory reset?

Comment: Yes I had, it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

For the music button to appear, you must have a valid Xbox live profile. Change the region of your Xbox Live profile to US. You'll get that music search.